Graalpy on macOS 15.1 unable to install numpy 1.23.2
I am using graalvm jdk graalvm-jdk-21.0.5+9.1 on MacOS 15.1 and I am trying to install numpy 1.23.2 using graalpy. I can see the following command:
/Users/Ishwardeepsingh/Downloads/chalkgraalpy/chalkgraalpy/target/classes/org.graalvm.python.vfs/venv/bin/graalpy -m pip install numpy==1.23.2
but the installation fails with an error
INFO: ar: adding 4 object files to build/temp.macosx-15.1-arm64-3.11/libnpymath.a
/opt/local/bin/ranlib: object: build/temp.macosx-15.1-arm64-3.11/libnpymath.a(npy_math.o) malformed object (unknown load command 1)
ar: internal ranlib command failed
Not sure what the issue is?

What's the output of /opt/local/bin/ranlib --version? If you installed it via brew, can you update it with brew update and brew upgrade ?

Is this an x86 or ARM mac, right now? Do you have a homebrew installation that was installed while you had a different architecture?
